# Cache results of pipe from BehaviorSubject

Tags: rxjs

Using rxjs, I have an expensive computation that maps the result coming out of a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
const obs$ = sameBehaviorSubject.pipe(map(expensiveComputation));
```

Then in multiple other parts of my code I subscribe to that observable. Each time I subscribe, it re-runs `expensiveComputation`. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use shareReplay:

```
const obs$ = sameBehaviorSubject.pipe(map(expensiveComputation), shareReplay(1));
```

Now you can subscribe to `obs$` multiple times without doing `expensiveComputation` multiple times.

Comment: Fantastic - I was hoping it would be something that easy! I actually even looked at that operator, but apparently it didn't click.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I've included this in a (very) small library of rxjs utils I've wanted in the past. It is the [`cache`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-rxjs-utils/typedoc/index.html#cache) function available in [`s-rxjs-utils`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-rxjs-utils).

---

**@siva636** gave this great answer: add `shareReplay(1)`. It does exactly what I asked.

I add this answer to show another alternative, with one small difference that turned out to be very important for me: add `publishReplay(1), refCount()`. So the solution is:

```
const obs$ = someBehaviorSubject.pipe(
  map(expensiveComputation),
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount(),
);
```

The difference occurs when the last subscriber unsubscribes from `obs$`: `shareReplay(1)` will keep its subscription open to `someBehaviorSubject`, whereas this solution will unsubscribe. I am creating these observables in Angular components that come and go over time, so it's important to me that when they are destroyed they completely clean up after themselves. `shareReplay(1)` leaked subscriptions that continued to build up over time, this solution does not.